# How to concat two column with '-' seperator in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, concatenation

I just want to concat two columns with seperator '-'.

These are the two columns, want to concat.

[image]

I am using this query to concat them

```
select concat(amt,endamt)as amount from mstcatrule
```

and it is giving me result this

[image]

But I Want that data of 2 columns should be sepearted by '-'

RESULT I WANT IS :

```
AMOUNT
0-0
100-99999999999
100-500
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do it with two concats:

```
select concat(concat(amt, '-'), endamt) as amount from mstcatrule;
```

`concat(amt,'-')` concatenates the `amt` with the dash and the resulting string is concatenated with `endamt`.

Answer (score 28):

Alternative:

```
select amt || '-' || endamt as amount from mstcatrule;
```

Comment: Can I use an underscore as delimiter? Doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle this works for me! :D

```
select amt||'-'||endamt as amount from mstcatrule
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use double pipe.

select amt || '-' || endamt as amount from mstcatrule;

You may have to convert amt and endamt to varchar

Answer (score -1):

**Alternative you can use under query**

```
select concat(amt,'-',endamt) as amount from mstcatrule;
```

Comment: You can use  ||'-'|| between two coloumn.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators003.htm#SQLRF51156

Answer (score -2):

A generic format for the query

```
Select concat(column1,'-',column2) as concatedCols from table_Name
```

For **Postgresql** only

Comment: How is this Answer different from [the answer by Md. Nasir Uddin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40067184/12695027)? Since the Question is tagged `pl/sql` I'm assuming this should run on an Oracle database, but the Oracle documentation does not allow for 3 parameters to [CONCAT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CONCAT.html#GUID-D8723EA5-C93A-45C3-83FB-1F3D2A4CEAF2), and trying this result in the error: `ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments`